# Walking cycle not ending in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a walking animation in pygame. I have it starting facing forward, and then if you move, the animation switches left or right, depending which way you move. But when I switch back to not moving, the animation doesn't change back.

```
    def animate(self):
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if self.vel.x != 0:
            self.walking = True
        else:
            self.walking = False
        # Show walk animation
        if self.walking:
            if now - self.last_update > 200:
                self.last_update = now
                self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.walk_frames_l)
                bottom = self.rect.bottom
                if self.vel.x > 0:
                    self.image = self.walk_frames_r[self.current_frame]
                else:
                    self.image = self.walk_frames_l[self.current_frame]
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.bottom = bottom

        # Show idle animation
        if not self.jumping and not self.walking:
            if now - self.last_update > 350:
                self.last_update = now
                self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.standing_frames)
                bottom = self.rect.bottom
                self.image = self.standing_frames[self.current_frame]
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.bottom = bottom
```

I figured out the reason it doesn't stop is to do with the movement logic in another part of my program, and the self.vel.x won't ever be 0, just extremely close to it. I fixed it by doing

```
if (self.vel.x // 1) != 0:
```

This makes it so that if the vel is 0.001 then it will just be 0.
This works if I am moving right, but if I move left it doesn't switch back. Does anyone know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going left, your velocity is negative. Floor division (`//`) always rounds down. This means that if your velocity is -0.001, it will round down to -1, which is not 0. You can confirm this by doing `print(self.vel.x // 1)` before your `if`.

The solution is to instead compare the absolute value of the velocity. You can get the absolute value by doing `abs(self.vel.x)`.